# Can someone explain to me this keys variable does

Tags: python-3.x, key, raspberry-pi3, evdev

I am developing a door lock using USB RFID and raspberry. I searched and almost all the python scripts I found with familiar code have the following variable keys. So can someone explain to me why they use it or why I have to use it too. Thank you in advance.
[python code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfRx3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a quick research from the [official documentation of Raspberry pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=202791)

It is a ***default authentication key*** which you were looking at those forums.
These keys are used for testing purposes but in the live products they use different ways to authenticate by scanning the RFID. [Here](https://gist.github.com/mattgorecki/6085344) is one example that is good for starters to understand how RFID scanning works.